# Calculating average time between customer orders and average order value in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL I have an orders table that represents orders made by customers of a store:

`SELECT * FROM orders`

| order_id | customer_id | value | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 188.01 | 2020-11-24 |
| 2 | 2 | 25.74 | 2022-10-13 |
| 3 | 1 | 159.64 | 2022-09-23 |
| 4 | 1 | 201.41 | 2022-04-01 |
| 5 | 3 | 357.80 | 2022-09-05 |
| 6 | 2 | 386.72 | 2022-02-16 |
| 7 | 1 | 200.00 | 2022-01-16 |
| 8 | 1 | 19.99 | 2020-02-20 |

For a specified time range (e.g. 2022-01-01 to 2022-12-31), I need to find the following:

- Average 1st order value
- Average 2nd order value
- Average 3rd order value
- Average 4th order value

E.g. the 1st purchases for each customer are:

- for customer_id 1, order_id 8 is their first purchase
- customer 2, order 6
- customer 3, order 5

So, the 1st-purchase average order value is `(19.99 + 386.72 + 357.80) / 3` = $254.84

This needs to be found for the 2nd, 3rd and 4th purchases also.

I also need to find the average time between purchases:

- order 1 to order 2
- order 2 to order 3
- order 3 to order 4

The final result would ideally look something like this:

| order_number | AOV | av_days_since_last_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 254.84 | 0 |
| 2 | 300.00 | 28 |
| 3 | 322.22 | 21 |
| 4 | 350.00 | 20 |

Note that average days since last order for order 1 would always be 0 as it's the 1st purchase.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select   order_number
        ,round(avg(value),2)                           as AOV
        ,coalesce(round(avg(days_between_orders),0),0) as av_days_since_last_order
from 
(
select   *
        ,row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by created_at) as order_number
        ,created_at - lag(created_at) over(partition by customer_id order by created_at) as days_between_orders
from     t
) t
where    created_at between '2022-01-01' and '2022-12-31'
group by order_number
order by order_number
```

| order_number | aov | av_days_since_last_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 372.26 | 0 |
| 2 | 25.74 | 239 |
| 3 | 200.00 | 418 |
| 4 | 201.41 | 75 |
| 5 | 159.64 | 175 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/T2Ut4nXC)

Answer (score 0):

Im suppose it should be something like this

```sql
WITH prep_data AS (
    SELECT  order_id,
            cuntomer_id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id, cuntomer_id ORDER BY created_at) AS pushcase_num,
            created_at,
            value
    FROM pushcases
    WHERE created_at BETWEEN :date_from AND :date_to
), prep_data2 AS (
    SELECT pd1.order_id,
           pd1.cuntomer_id,
           pd1.pushcase_num
           pd2.created_at - pd1.created_at AS date_diff,
           pd1.value
    FROM prep_data pd1
    LEFT JOIN prep_data pd2 ON (pd1.order_id = pd2.order_id AND pd1.cuntomer_id = pd2.cuntomer_id AND pd1.pushcase_num = pd2.pushcase_num+1)
)
SELECT  order_id,
        cuntomer_id,
        pushcase_num,
        avg(value) AS avg_val,
        avg(date_diff) AS avg_date_diff
FROM prep_data2
GROUP BY pushcase_num
```

Comment: the data is problematic so I deleted my answer, but you're missing a couple of things. You need to group by pushcase_num and also calculate the day difference average between purchases.

Comment: Sorry for this. Im not shure I understand how to calculate the day difference average between purchases. Perhaps somebody can inprove my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "the data is problematic"? And what was wrong with your answer @DannySlor? Seems to produce the correct result?

Comment: The specified time range you have has zero sales in it.

Comment: Use lag instead of inner joining the tables. It's much better.

Comment: Thanks Danny. I've updated the time range in my question to include some orders in it. Does the answer you provided (https://dbfiddle.uk/XBPMsCA7) work @DannySlor?

Comment: @DannyAdams I posted an answer, but the question now is if you want to count the first order per customer in this time frame as first order.

Comment: Thanks @DannySlor! Not sure what you mean by "the question now is if you want to count the first order per customer in this time frame as first order."?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249054/discussion-between-dannyslor-and-danny-adams).